# How to run this mysql docker image build locally

Tags: mysql, image, docker

My host os is Ubuntu 18. Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c

Here is the docker file:-

```
FROM mysql:5.7
ADD  docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=dockercon2035
ENV MYSQL_USER=gordon
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
```

docker-entrypoint-initdb.d has initialize_db.sql

```
    CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dateOfBirth` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`emailAddress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`firstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`lastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
`userName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I build it as: `docker build -t reg-database .`

Then I tried to run it as:-

```
docker run reg-database -p 3306:3306 -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" -e "MYSQL_USER=gordon"
```

I got the following error:-

```
[Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.
2020-07-18 09:09:30+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
    command was: mysqld -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_USER=gordon --verbose --help
    2020-07-18T09:09:30.861935Z 0 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown option '-p'
2020-07-18T09:09:30.864121Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

how can I run this docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `2020-07-18T09:09:30.861935Z 0 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown option '-p'`

The error is because of your first docker run command,

```
docker run reg-database -p 3306:3306 -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" -e "MYSQL_USER=gordon"
```

anything after docker `image name` will be considered as an argument for the MySQL process. so `-p 3306:3306` and `-e ...` are also pass as an argument.

correct command should be

```
docker run -it --rm -p 3306:3306 -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" -e "MYSQL_USER=gordon" reg-database
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker container run -d --name mysql -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=password reg-database
```

you can give any name and any password